# How to bind ngStyle to ng-conent in angular2

Tags: angular, ng-style, angular2-ngcontent

I try to bind ngStyle to ng-content, it doesn't work, see below example:

```
<ng-content select="panel-one" [ngStyle]="{'width':size+'px'}"></ng-content>
```

I search on internet only find below solution,

```
::content >>> panel-one {width:50px}
```

=>from https://plnkr.co/edit/T5CoP5qmd4nzIPAFjLNQ?p=preview

but it can not dynamic change the style value.

Answer (score 1):

`<ng-content>` is never added to the DOM. It's just an internal placeholder for Angular2. The `[ngStyle]` doesn't have any effect at all.

Maybe using a wrapper does what you want

```
  <div [ngStyle]="{'width':size+'px'}">
    <ng-content select="panel-one" ></ng-content>
  </div>
```